# useEffect - infinite loop when the tracked variable hasnt changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to useEffect, but reading the doc my problem doesnt seem to make any sense.
At the beginning of my file, I am instantiating a state and a variable

```
const [moduleDisplay, setModule] = useState("")
let moduleRender = <div>Hello World</div>

useEffect(() => {
    setModule(moduleRender);
},[moduleRender]);
```

From what I observed upon first render, the actual rendered component `moduleDisplay` starts off as `""`, the useEffect function gets mounted and somehow triggers and `moduleDisplay`'s state is changed to `moduleRender`, which is the `Hello World` component, triggering a re-render.

However, at no other point are any of these variables/functions used (aside from rendering moduleDisplay in the actual render), so I dont see how moduleRender is being changed in anyway, shape, or form. But this causes an infinite rendering loop and I dont get why.

Comment: I think everytime the component re-renders, `let moduleRender = <div>Hello World</div>` is called, which triggers the useEffect to be called again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`useState` inside `useEffect` causes a `re-render`. In case of a `re-render` `moduleRender = <div>Hello World</div>` gets assigned to `<div>Hello World</div>` again and `useEffect` hits in.

Here you can find a pretty good writing about your problem:
https://medium.com/@andrewmyint/infinite-loop-inside-useeffect-react-hooks-6748de62871